# DataGridViewComboBox Index Changed Event Trouble

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

Hope someone can help on this one. I have a bug in my code that I cant fix. I'm testing out using Selected Index Event handling with DataGridView control.

I have created two columns:-

Column 0 is a `DataGridViewTextBoxColum`
Column 1 is a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`

I have gave my `ComboBox` Column a Datasource that is a small `DataTable` consisting of two Columns which are `Username` & `UserID`.

The Display Member is set to the Username Column and I have the UserID column set as the ValueMember.

All I'm looking to do is Column 0(`DataGridViewTextBox`), populate with the `UserID`(`ValueMember`) on the Index Changed event for the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`.

It works fine when I first load the program. The `IndexChanged` Event Fires without any error. But if I try to select the `ComboBox` in the new row, it is clearing the value in combobox from the previous row, and then throwing a Null Reference Exception.

I have listed the Code Below and Highlighted the line of the code that it fails at :-

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadData();
        }

        public OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\riversd\Desktop\Test.accdb");

        public string sql = "SELECT * FROM [AgentList]";

        private void LoadData()
        {
            dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;

            DataTable dt = AgentTable(sql, con);

            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn textbox = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(textbox);

            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            combo.DataSource = dt;
            combo.DisplayMember = "agentName";
            combo.ValueMember = "AgentID";


            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(combo);

        }

        public DataTable AgentTable(string SQL, OleDbConnection con)
        {
            var AgentList = new DataTable();
            var SELECTcommand = new OleDbCommand(SQL, con);
            var adaptor = new OleDbDataAdapter();

            adaptor.SelectCommand = SELECTcommand;

            con.Open();
            adaptor.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            adaptor.Fill(AgentList);
            con.Close();

            return AgentList;
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewColumn col = dataGridView1.Columns[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex];
            if (col is DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
            {
                dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
            }
        }

        private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1 && e.Control is ComboBox)
            {

                ComboBox comboBox = e.Control as ComboBox;
                comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += LastColumnComboSelectionChanged;
            }
        }

        private void LastColumnComboSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            var currentcell = dataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress;
            var sendingCB = sender as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
            DataGridViewTextBoxCell cel = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[currentcell.Y].Cells[0];

            // HERE IS THE LINE THAT THROES EXCEPTION WHEN MOVING FROM
            // ONE COMBOXCELL to another.
            cel.Value = sendingCB.SelectedValue.ToString();


        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing line:-
`DataGridViewTextBoxCell cel = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[currentcell.Y].Cells[0];`

to

`DataGridViewTextBoxCell cel = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[currentcell.Y].Cells[1];`